# Wired Ethernet on Mac Mini with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, mac, mac-mini

I installed 16.04 as a double boot on my 2011 Mac Mini and all seemed to work - until I tried to connect to my network (wired and wireless). I get the message that the connection is established after quite a while, but no IPv4 is assigned, and I don't see any eth0 interface (in /dev). The weirdest thing is that I can get a connection working with a guest login on my router. That connection is open, if I use the encrypted wireless connection to my network I don't get an IPv4 (no inet line in ifconfig).
Do I need proprietary drivers for the network interfaces, and if so, which ones might that be?
Thanks - Merlin

Comment: What is the output of:  sudo lshw -C network

Comment: I just got one step further:
The command
sudo apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree broadcom-sta-dkms
and a reboot got my wireless to work now, so I can at least connect to my local network through the wireless adapter.
Now I still have to find a solution to get the wired gigibit adapter to work - there just MUST be a way - hopefully there is a kind soul out there who knows  :-)

Comment: oops - ActionParsnip - didn't see that question of the lshw output - here it is (that is with the wireless already working:

  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0f0
       version: 10
       serial: 3c:07:54:0c:52:24
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz

Comment: capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=57765-v1.42 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:a0400000-a040ffff memory:a0410000-a041ffff

Comment: *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 02
       serial: 28:cf:da:05:ba:15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.0.145 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:a0600000-a0603fff

Comment: If you run:   ping 8.8.8.8        do you get replies?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I've got the same problem on Mac Mini 3.1 and Centos 7. Even at during installation network settings, or after install and `ip addr` shows no other interface except `lo` loopback.